# Accordion not closing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an accordion on a site I am working on. It has an annoying bug which I can't figure out.

If you click on the arrow, the accordion will open and close correctly. If you click on the title, the accordion will open but will simply bounce when you try to close it.

Both the title and the arrow are within the same anchor so I understand why this is happening.

The code is:

```
<div class="accordion">
    <div class="accordion-section">

        <div class="tab">
            <a class="accordion-title accordion-section-button l2" href="#accordion-205">
                <h3>How do you differ from estate agents?</h3>
             </a>

             <div id="accordion-205" class="accordion-section-content">
                 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc mattis ante eget quam volutpat, ac pulvinar massa ornare.</p>
             </div>
         </div>


         <div class="tab">
             <a class="accordion-title accordion-section-button l2" href="#accordion-204">
                 <h3>Why would an estate agent prefer speaking or dealing with yourself?</h3>
             </a>
             <div id="accordion-204" class="accordion-section-content">
                 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc mattis ante eget quam volutpat, ac pulvinar massa ornare.</p>
              </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    function close_accordion_section() {
        $('.accordion .accordion-section-button').removeClass('active');
        $('.accordion .accordion-section-content').slideUp(300).removeClass('open');
    }

    $('.accordion-section-button').click(function(e) {
        // Grab current anchor value
        var currentAttrValue = $(this).attr('href');

        if($(e.target).is('.active')) {
            close_accordion_section();
        }else {
            close_accordion_section();

           // Add active class to section title
           $(this).addClass('active');
           // Open up the hidden content panel
           $('.accordion ' + currentAttrValue).slideDown(300).addClass('open'); 
        }

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is this line:

```
if($(e.target).is('.active')) {
```

When you click on the `<h3>` the element `e.target` will be the `<h3>` and not the `<a>`. Instead try something like this:

```
if($(this).is('.active')) {
```

Note that this is now consistent with the line where you add that class further down.

Answer (score 0):

If you like, you can reduce everything to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.accordion-section-button').click(function(e) {
        close_accordion_section();
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $('.accordion ' + this.attributes.href.value)[(this.classList.contains('active')) ? 'slideDown' : 'slideUp'](300)
                    .toggleClass('open');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: In the original code it would only allow one section to be expanded at once, potentially requiring both a `slideUp` and `slideDown` at the same time on two different sections. I don't believe your code currently handles that scenario.

Comment: The original question (since edited) included a link to a URL where it was possible to test the behaviour. If you expanded one section and then tried to expand a different section it would animate the collapse of the original section at the same time as expanding the new section. Unless I'm missing something I can't see where your code handles that.

Comment: @skirtle added **close_accordion_section();** to close any previous open tab..... Thanks

Comment: @skirtle In any case,that way is wrong, because it closes all tabs, not the active one. isn't it?